# in html, how to open a new window in IE even when using other browser?

Tags: html, browser

```
<a   href="http://192.168.1.1" 
onclick="Popup=window.open('http://192.168.1.1','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=
no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=800,height=300,left=300,top=23'); 
return false;" > 
<button type="button">button</button></a>
```

If i'm browser this page in firefox, it pop up a new window in firefox when i click button.
if in chrome, then it pop up in chrome.

What if i want the pop up window always open in IE even when im browser this page in other browser?
Thanks!

Comment: What if a user doesn't have IE?

Comment: the user will, because the pop up window only works in IE..thats why it must force to open a ie window

Comment: lol the user will? exactly how are you checking to see that the user has IE installed? My macbook doesn't have IE. If I'm in safari, what method do you use? See what we mean? Also, web functions are specific to the browser running them. Imagine the massive security hole if a browser allowed a site to sniff out the programs on the computer running the page, or for that matter execute them! You could call any hidden executable on the system that way so there's no difference between IE and any virus waiting to be called. Fraid there's nothing for this one.

Comment: not possible. And just because your code only works in IE that doesn't mean the user has IE.

Comment: Take a step back and imagine the chaos that would ensue if browser makers allowed links to execute other programs directly... oh wait, IE already did that! It's a _good_ thing that you can't do this in HTML. It's a _bad_ thing if something only works in IE. Sorry if that's not what you want to hear ;-)

Comment: If a website I was viewing in Chrome opened a window in IE, I would never visit that site again.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers cannot start other programs except with a plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  It breaks the sandbox model -- javascript in chrome, firefox, etc., executes in a security sandbox and there are lots of things it can't do.  It can't save files to your hard disk (malicious code could overwrite your OS) -- it can't open arbitrary executables or start processes (malicious code could run a virus/malware).  Javascript doesn't have the ability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, browsers cannot start other programs without plugins or similar functionality.

I think your best bet is to detect IE on the other page. I don't believe there's a way to force IE. You could provide the link for them to easily copy and paste into IE, such as in a text box that is fully selected when they click in it.